# Напряжение, ток и мощность для кабеля и измерителя

Tags: железо, физика, электроника

Если заявлено, что кабель рассчитан на ток до 30 вольт силой до 5 ампер, то это два независимых лимита или их можно перемножить и получить 150 Вт? Можно ли такой кабель использовать для 5V * 6A?

А к электронному измерителю тока применимы те же рассуждения, что и для кабеля, или тут уже играют роль другие факторы?

[image: картинка измерителя]

Comment: Для проводов главный фактор - чтобы не перегрелся до белого каления как "лампа Ильича". Если дать необходимое охлаждение, проследить за целостностью оплётки провода, можно превышать лимит мощности и в два и в три раза. Ну а прибор - это смотря какой прибор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Это два независимых лимита или их можно перемножить и получить 150 Вт?

Да, это два независимых параметра.

Допустимый ток для кабеля определяется удельным сопротивлением проводника. При превышении оного, во-первых, на кабеле начнутся потери энергии, а, во-вторых, это приведёт к тому, что он начнёт греться, что может привести к пожару.

Допустимое напряжение определяется сопротивлением пробоя изоляции. Для большинства силовых проводов это 1000В.

> Можно ли такой кабель использовать для 5V * 6A?

Я этого не говорил, но при небольшом превышении тока (до 20% номинала) ничего страшного с проводом обычно не происходит. Но делать это можно на свой страх и риск, с особой осторожностью и не оставлять без присмотра и т.д. и т.п.

30В — скорей всего просто штампик, а не реальная характеристика.

<sub>**Дисклеймер**: я не электрик, не электротехник и вообще все советы по безопасности от незнакомца в интернете стоит воспринимать до некоторой степени скептически.</sub>

---

> А к электронному измерителю тока применимы те же рассуждения, что и для кабеля, или тут уже играют роль другие факторы?

В общем то применимы, но тут есть и другие факторы.

В простейшем случае, электронный амперметр устроен так, что просто измеряет напряжение с помощью АЦП на шунте, куске проводника с заранее известным сопротивлением. А потом просто по закону Ома считает ток из известного сопротивления и напряжения. Он просто не сможет измерять ток больше того на который спроектирован, а при значительном превышении тока шунт просто начнёт греться. Также обычно последовательно шунту устанавливают плавкий предохранитель, который просто перегорает при превышении тока.